# Quasar : How to call a function in axios.ts?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, quasar-framework

I am using `Quasar Framework` with `TypeScript` and trying to get `data` using `axios`. I have referred to the documentation from https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files#accessing-data-from-boot-files, however, it does not show me the `TypeScript` version, but only `axios.js`, so I am confused.

src/boot/axios.ts

```js
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $axios: AxiosInstance;
  }
}

const getData = () => {
  axios
    .get(
      'URL'
    )
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
} 

export default boot(({ Vue } : { Vue: any}) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
  Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;
  Vue.prototype.$getData = getData;
});
```

src/pages/VisitorSummary.vue

```html
<template>
  <q-page padding>
    <!-- content -->
    <button v-on:click="getData">TEST</button>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import boot from '../boot/axios'; // <-- I don't have to import this

export default Vue.extend({
  methods: {
    getData: function() {
      console.log('test');
      this.$getData(); // <-- I tried this too..

     // getData() { // <-- I know I can use this in-place
    //   this.$axios
    //     .get(
    //       'URL'
    //     )
    //     .then(response => {
    //       console.log(`response.data`, response.data);
    //     })
    //     .catch(error => {
    //       console.log(`error`, error);
    //     });
    // }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

When I run this code, I see this error below

> BootFile.default is not a function

What am I missing there?

Comment: As you added the $getData into the Vue prototype, it Is accessible via `this`.
Instead of importing the boot file use: `this.$getData()`

Comment: It's even better to use $axios in-place: `this.$axios.get('URL).then(({data})=> ...).catch...`

Comment: If you persist to use `getData` defined in the boot file (It doesn't make sense to me at all), you should export it first and import it everywhere needed. The boot file is an entry file that runs at the startup to initialize/configure the app.

Comment: @Mr. I had also tried `this.$getData()`, but it says `Property '$getData' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, { getData: () => void; }, unknown, Readonly<Record<never, any>>>'. Did you mean 'getData'?`

Comment: @Mr. so you mean I just get data in `VisitorSummary.vue` file right away?

Comment: @Mr. Yes I know what boot file does, but the reason why I  put `getData` function in boot file is because I want to use the function commonly and globally

And I have edited my code in accordance with what you mentioned